# firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged No provider for AngularFire

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I get the error

Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for AngularFire!

When I tried to call `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`. 
Don't know why this happens. Please help.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Login } from '../pages/login/login';

import firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = Login;
  isAuthenticated = false;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "AIzaSyC94rD8wXG0aRLTcG29qVGw8CFfvCK7XVQ",
      authDomain: "myfirstfirebaseproject-6da6c.firebaseapp.com",
    }); 

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.rootPage = HomePage;
      } else {
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
        this.rootPage = Login;
      }
    });

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add app.module.ts?

Comment: What do I have to add in app module?

Comment: Does your project include angularfire injected in the app.module.ts? You might paste the contents of this file as @suraj asks above

Answer (score 0):

Your config isn't set up properly. You should have this code in your app.module.ts, not in your component.

```
import {
    AngularFireModule,
    AuthMethods,
    AuthProviders
} from 'angularfire2';

...

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp({
            apiKey: '<some-key>',
            authDomain: '<some-project-authdomain>',
            databaseURL: '<some-database-URL>',
            storageBucket: '<some-storage-bucket>'
        }, {
            method: AuthMethods.Password,
            provider: AuthProviders.Password
        }),
        BrowserModule,
        ...
    ]
})
class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

This is where you should have the above code. If you don't have the provider set, you'll keep getting the error.